# Why can't I update .bashrc on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: bashrc

My `.bashrc` file before updating is as below and my Hadoop worked as well:

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
HADOOP_INSTALL=/usr/local/hadoop
PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/bin
PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/sbin
HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_INSTALL/lib/native
HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_INSTALL/lib"
```

I just added two paths as below

```
$ export HBASE_HOME="/home/hadoop/hbase/hbase-0.98.18-hadoop2"
PATH="$HBASE_HOME/bin:$PATH"
```

but most commands (as su username or clear or sudo etc.) are not working. When I wanted to change the `.bashrc`, I see this error:

[image]

How can I reach `.bashrc` to change it?

Comment: you don't need `sudo` to edit your `.bashrc`.

Answer (score 3):

You do not have `/usr/bin` in your path. To run sudo you have to type the whole path for sudo

```
/usr/bin/sudo nano .bashrc
```

If `/bin` is also not in your path you will specify the full path for nano  like this

```
/usr/bin/sudo /bin/nano .bashrc
```

And finally you might also need to provide the path for `.bashrc`

```
/usr/bin/sudo /bin/nano ~/.bashrc
```

or

```
/usr/bin/sudo /bin/nano $HOME/.bashrc
```

or

```
/usr/bin/sudo /bin/nano /home/<username>/.bashrc
```

where you replace the `<username>` with the username that you have. And in the end you need to find out how did you manage to corrupt your $PATH.